# Can I archive in Outlook if it is not running in cached mode?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, archiving, cached-exchange-mode

The client is Outlook 2010. It has almost a 12Gb mailbox. I want to run a series of archives to drastically reduce the size of the mailbox. Can I run the archives if Outlook is not in cached mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Outlook archiving moves the data to a separate file locally on your machine. Cached mode is a separate concept that refers to your machine having a local copy of data that is stored on your mail server for faster and offline access.

Please note that when you archive the data it will no longer exist on the server, so if you lose the archive file you will lose your archived data.

Answer (score 2):

Autoarchiving only can pull from what is stored locally on the computer. Cached mode determines how much is locally downloaded to your computer. So if you have your cached mode set to 6 months and are trying to archive stuff that is 1 year old, the autoarchive will not see that e-mail and will not pull it into the archive. To allow it to archive it, you should set the cached mode to more than 1 year, or set it to ALL (furthest to the right on the slider), so that the autoarchive can pull it all in.